# Typeorm refactor blacklisting. One entity relation

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I wanna implement user blacklisting in my app.

Simple use case: logged in user can "blacklist" another user, so I would need `user.blacklist` an array of each blacklisted users id.

My backend is made with TypeOrm, here is my user entity:

```
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  @Length(3, 21)
  pseudo: string;

  @Column()
  @Length(4, 100)
  password: string;

  // ...

  @OneToMany(() => Blacklist, (blacklist) => blacklist.user)
  blacklist: Blacklist[];

  @ManyToMany(() => Blacklist)
  @JoinTable()
  blacklists: Blacklist[];
}
```

As you can see I tryed something, here is my blacklist entity:

```
export class Blacklist {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.blacklist)
  user: User;

  @ManyToMany(() => User, (user) => user.blacklists)
  users: User[]
}
```

This is actually working. But I wont let it like this because it's very ugly and very bad.

My (mysql) database looks like this:

```
| user       | blacklist   | user_blacklists_blacklist |
|------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| id         | id          | userId                    |
| pseudo     | userId      | blacklistId               |
| ...        |             |                           |
```

I would prefering this:

```
| user       | blacklist        | 
|------------|------------------|
| id         | id               |
| pseudo     | userId           |
| ...        | blacklistedUserId|
```

At least the database i don't care so much but 2 relations to users in the blacklist entity, I guess there is much simpler..

I tryed with @Tree, not working, I wanted only children to fake childrens as blacklisted users but it create parent anyway.

It's the first time I use TypeOrm, some suggests / direct help will be very appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I found a better/simpler way:

I removed Blacklist entity and the relations in User.
And I added this in my User entity instead:

```
@ManyToMany(() => User, (user) => user.blacklisted)
@JoinTable({
   name: 'user_blacklist',
   joinColumn: {
     name: 'userId',
     referencedColumnName: 'id',
  },
  inverseJoinColumn: {
     name: 'blacklistedUserId',
     referencedColumnName: 'id',
  },
})
blacklist: User[];

@ManyToMany(() => User, (user) => user.blacklist)
blacklisted: User[];
```

And that's all. I just have a user_blacklist table with the two columns in @JoinTable().